# Write a unit test for scroll event listener in my React custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

This is my React JS custom hook for creating infinite scroll:

```
const useInfiniteScroll = (callback) => {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
    if (ref.current && window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= ref.current.offsetHeight - 10 && !isFetching) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    }
  }, 100);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    callback();
    setIsFetching(false);
  }, [isFetching]);

  return [ref, isFetching, setIsFetching];
};

export default useInfiniteScroll;
```

This is a unit test I Wrote for it but It would not get passed:

```
test('should call the handleScroll function when the user scrolls', () => {
    const handleScroll = jest.fn();
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useInfiniteScroll(jest.fn));
  
    fireEvent.scroll(window);
    expect(handleScroll).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
```

Can anyone help me to correct my unit test?
The Error is:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Comment: What connection do you think there is between the `handleScroll` you define in your test and the one that gets called by the hook?

Comment: Nothing. One is an event handler, and another is a fetch function that should be provided for using this hook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the async statement in your code? try

```
await fireEvent.scroll(window)
```

And btw testing you are testing implementation detail. i.e, if the function name is changed, your test will break also. Instead, you can check if new data being fetched or now when the user hits the bottom scroll.

For more .. check out [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) article

Comment: No. I think the problem is something else about how should I mock my event handler function.

Comment: You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw library